# How to use wmic to kill a cmd.exe instance searching by it's command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have seen that is possible to use `wmic` to find the `id` of a process searching for the `command line` which was used to start it.

But I have 2 problems.

- I need to use this in a batch file so I cannot read the output of the wmic and call the taskkill I must use some kind of grep
- I couldn't find how to search for a partial match. I prefer to search for a piece of the commandline.

What I could find is this example:

```
wmic process where "CommandLine=start.bat", pid
```

But what I would like to do is more similar to:

```
wmic process where "CommandLine like %start.bat%", pid | taskkill
```

This is what I mean by command line:
"cmd.exe" /c C:\Mysql\start.bat"

Is there a way to **kill** a process searching for the command line which started it?

Comment: if it's not clear please give me a suggestion so that I can improve the question.

Comment: My first thought would be to look up the ID by command-line, and the kill by ID, but I'm not sure I follow exactly what you mean by "use wmic to find the id of a process searching for the command line which was used to start it", so you question is a little unclear. In addition to that, for improving your question to avoid down-votes, I'm thinking people feel it's lacking research effort...  What have you tried already?  (PS I didn't downvote you ;) ).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 thanks a lot for the help, I don't know exactly how to write it.. I want to write the command in a batch file so I cannot execute wmic, read the output and call taskkill. It must happen by batch.. And I don't know how to use filters like * or % in the search of wmic; I would like something similar to: "wmic process where "CommandLine like %start%", pid | kill that process"

Comment: The problem is that is very hard to formulate this kind of questions in an elegant way without knowing the nomenclature

Comment: Looks like you want `xargs`. There are some Windows versions out there, for example with Cygwin.

Comment: @DanielB thanks! but, I cannot solve with the standard windows utities?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How to use wmic to kill a cmd.exe instance searching by it's command
> line?

It seems that you can do this natively from Windows batch with the below format. Just plug in your batch file name (which is the string found with `WMIC` `COMMANDLINE` option) in the `%start.bat%` part as I did below—I used `start.bat` in my example below just as you used in your example.

**WMIC (kill specific batch file process example)**

```
WMIC PROCESS WHERE "COMMANDLINE LIKE '%start.bat%'" CALL TERMINATE
```

---

> Now, let's terminate Notepad. Please note the PID is different now.
> What we do is the following command, a simple sort of sentence-like
> statement, where we determine the condition and the action, plus the
> return value so you can check the sanity and success of your
> administration work.
>
> ```
> process where processid="1000" call terminate
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> [Source](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/windows-wmic.html)

### Supporting Resource

- [WMIC - The Windows secret weapon](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/windows-wmic.html)

Comment: This will also call terminate on `wmic.exe` itself, since the specified string matches its own command line.